# Histogram with string x axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter

Can a histogram/bar chart be displayed with string x axis titles ? Below I'm attempting to display the chart with pre-configured x and y axis values where each x axis value is a string range.

Below code :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = ['1 - 100','200 - 400','400 - 600','600 - 800','800 - 100']
y = [10,2,3,4,5]

plt.bar(x,y,align='center') # A bar chart
plt.xlabel('Number iterations')
plt.ylabel('Time taken')
plt.show()
```

causes error :

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'float
```

Comment: Can you provide your Matplotlib version? This works fine for me.

Comment: Using strings for the catagorical values was introduced in [`matplotlib 2.1.0`](https://matplotlib.org/users/prev_whats_new/whats_new_2.1.0.html). Make sure your version is 2.1.0 or higher. As @miradulo says, this example does indeed work with a recent version of matplotlib

Comment: @miradulo please see my answer.

Comment: @tom please see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @miradulo & @tom comments the issue indeed is using matplotlib pre 2.1.0. This code achieves similar effect :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700]
y = [10,2 , 5 , 6 , 6 , 7 , 8]

plt.bar(x,y,align='center', width=30) # A bar chart
plt.xlabel('Number iterations')
plt.ylabel('Time taken')
plt.show()
```

But unfortunately does not include string ranges.

Answer (score -1):

Remove the - signs. This is turning your integers into strings.

If using a histogram use bins = 200.

Are you sure you don't have a mistake with 1-100?